# Excel VBA - scroll area run time error in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, scroll

I have
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SOMMA 1").ScrollArea = "C3:C302"`
in `Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)`

And the sheet is protected.

I don't understand why, sometimes when the user opens the file, the visible columns are not A, B, C, etc but C, D, E, etc. This happens to me with Excel 2019 that I have at home and with Excel 2010 that I have at work.

I thought of "forcing" a scroll by using this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SOMMA 1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
```

And this works in Excel 2019 and 2010.

The problem arises when I add this last row of code, because it works in Excel 2019 but not in Excel 2010 that I have in the office:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SOMMA 1").ScrollArea = "C3:C302"
```

In Excel 2010 I have a run time error "not supported method" (I'm not sure about the actual error because I use Excel in Italian)

How could I write the code to define the scroll area and at the same time have it "fixed" all the times as it should be?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think ScrollArea sets the visible range that first appears on screen. Maybe `Application.Goto`? In other words you can't limit the view to c3:c302.

Comment: If you wanted it `fixed" all the times` then you'd need to initiate it via a `Workbook_Open()` event.

Comment: @kevin9999, can you elaborate your interesting advice please?